# What does this p2p info mean from the daemon log?

Tags: p2p, nodes, daemon, logs

```
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.864931 [P2P0][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]NOTIFY_NEW_BLOCK (hop 3)
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.865073 [P2P5][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]NOTIFY_NEW_BLOCK (hop 4)
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.865221 [P2P1][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]NOTIFY_NEW_BLOCK (hop 2)
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.865326 [P2P2][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]NOTIFY_NEW_TRANSACTIONS
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.865449 [P2P2][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]NOTIFY_NEW_BLOCK (hop 2)
2016-Jul-30 22:32:06.835879 [P2P5][x.x.x.x:18080 OUT]COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC
-field1-------------------| |-f2-| -field3----------|----field4----------
```

So, field 1 is obvious the date and time (local system time?).

**Field 2 (here as f2) - what is this? P2P instance 1? There only ever seems to be 0-9, even when my daemon says I have 40 OUT connections.**

Field 3 is the IP and port of the peer, and whether the local node initiated the connection or the peer node.

**Field 6 is the command or notification? What does the hop mean?** Does hop 0 mean that the local daemon is the first to receive this block notification (with the peer node being the solver of the block), and hop 1 would mean that there is 1 other node between you and the block solver?

And what is `command_timed_sync` mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about internal logs that are subject to arbitrary change

Comment: well this data has to be somewhere.

Comment: @user36303 can you explain why questions about internal daemon logs are off topic?

Comment: I don't know if they're off topic, but my opinion is that they should be, because they're internal and subject to arbitrary change, as I commented above. Questions on this site are meant as an archive, really, and as soon as the P2P layer gets rewritten, or even before that, that log might go away. Besides, I don't think explaining every internal log to non programmers is a good use of my time, but maybe others might think answering these has value, and they can do so.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure random debug log questions are on topic for stack exchange, but...

Field 2 is the thread logging this message.

Hop is the (untrusted) number of peers forwarding the object.

COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC is one of the P2P traffic messages.